# DreamPie doesn't work with Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.2

My favorite Python shell is [DreamPie](http://dreampie.sourceforge.net/) and I want to use it with Python 3.2. I've used the "add interpreter" DreamPie app and added Python 3.2. When opening the Python 3.2 DreamPie instance I get the following error message:

[image: DreamPie Error Message]

Indeed, Python 3.2 isn't mentioned on the DreamPie website as supported, but I still want to know if there's a way to make it work anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick search of the DreamPie issues found [Can't launch python 3.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dreampie/+bug/716377) which contains the following workaround in the first comment:

> To fix the issue edit `\dreampie\subp_main.py`, replace:
>
> ```
> sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
> ```
>
> with:
>
> ```
> import platform 
> if not "3.2" in platform.python_version(): 
>     sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
> ```
>
> Tested on WindowsXP SP3, both Python2.7 and Python3.2 can be used with
>   this fix.

There are a number of other suggested workarounds in later comments.

**Edit:**

A fix for this issue has already been committed but is not in a stable release as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been fixed and works in the latest stable DreamPie release, 1.2.1. I'm using it and it works fine; I tested with both Python 3.2 and 3.4. On the DreamPie [homepage](http://www.dreampie.org/) it says:

> Supports virtually all Python implementations: 2.5+, 3.1+, Jython,
>   IronPython and PyPy.

Here's a screenshot I took:

[image]