# How to use Python3.2 with Dreampie? [UBUNTU]

Tags: python, configuration, python-3.x, ide

I have a question.

I try to learn Python and of all programmer's tools I found Dreampie the most suitable. But, my dreampie always automatically sets Python 2.7. I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354376/dreampie-doesnt-work-with-python-3-2) and following the instructions, I changed both subp_main.py and subp_main.pyc (based on the first). Yet, it's still Python 2.7.

Telling truth, I suppose there should be some way to choose between the two versions, but I did not found anything in the Net or in program options. According to [this topic](https://answers.launchpad.net/dreampie/+question/147706) writing "dreampie python3" inside the program should work, but dreampie inform me that the syntax is invalid (?).

[I quess the solution is very easy, but none of searchable things would help...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open a **Terminal** window (or Run dialog `Alt+F2`) and type in the command as follows and press Enter:

```
dreampie python3
```

It's not python syntax but shell syntax so you are running the `dreampie` application with `python3` as argument.

Comment: At least with 1.2.1 it doesn't support python3, you get a syntax error: except StartError, e: